# Issue installing Qgis 1.8 Openlayers Plugin on Win XP

Tags: qgis

I recently installed Qgis on a Win XP PC. All seems fine. I went to install the Openlayers plugin using http://build.sourcepole.ch/qgis/plugins.xml and I get and error saying the plugins directory doesn't exist. The error reports the location as:
C:/Documents and Settings/osc/.qgis//python/plugins
The plugins directory does exist but the path displayed in the error seems to have one too many forward slashes - i.e. '.qgis//'.

I've successfully used the plugin installer for the Openlayers plugin many times on Linux so is there something special about Win XP to consider?

Comment: I got it installed here on XP and Windows 7 without problems. Perhaps a bug in a recent installer version. You might contact sourcepole directly or open a ticket at http://hub.qgis.org/projects/openlayers/issues

Comment: Thanks Andre. I emailed a couple of sourcepole guys directly but haven't heard from them. I wasn't aware of the issues so I'll try there.

Comment: Alternatively, you can extract http://build.sourcepole.ch/qgis/openlayers.zip manually and put it in the folder .qgis/python/plugins. Thats all the installer does.

Answer (score 2):

This issue seems to be fixed. I following Andre's advice and asked the user to install another plugin. This was successful. I then asked the user to try to reinstall the Openlayers plugin. There is a new version (1.0.0) and this installed along side the old plugin. All seems to be fine now!

The fix seems to have been to install the new plugin.

P.s. The new Openlayers plugin works much better with 'on the fly' projection.